# Why was this specific answer downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer

I know that nobody except the downvoters can know exactly why they did. And I do not really care for the 4 rep points.

But I'm here for little more than one year, and I would really like to know whether something is specially bad in my answer to avoid doing it again. I have already posted poor answers but I normally could understand why they bad and often deleted them unless they contain something interesting. But here I do not really understand why it deserved -2.

It concerns Python and is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29897201/3545273)

Comment: Obligatory:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Nice ! Hope keys have now been found :-)

Comment: I don't know Python, but judging by Makato's answer, it sounds like your answer falls in a category of answers that I regularly downvote: answers which are technically correct and technically solve the specific problem, but are short-sighted, miss the big picture, promote bad practice (which will inevitably encourage more questions on SO caused by not getting the best answer in the first place), or just have some sort of general problem in spite of technically answering the question. Usually though, I leave a comment and a better answer.

Comment: @nhgrif : thank you for your comment. It is exactly what I would have expected as an answer : one reason why this answer was poor : I would never have use it but did neither say it was dangerous nor why. It actually deserved the downvotes ...

Comment: I agree; even if it remains anonymous, I think a down vote should be required to be accompanied by a comment so that the person could learn from the mistake, and others looking at it could decide whether they think it was warranted or not.  I don't see how a down vote with no comment benefits anyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main point is that people didn't feel that your solution was a good idea.

As a Python developer, I'm somewhat inclined to agree; that sort of form is unwieldy, not portable and other solutions (like the debugger) are simpler to execute.

It's likely that your solution wasn't wrong.  It's likely that people didn't think that it was optimal.  That's likely all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted a confirmation. Even if I still cannot imagine what is not portable :-)